Labeling loop in the commutative diagram
The following code yields the bold part.
\[   \begin{tikzcd}[
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},
    execute at end picture={
      \path (mycd-2-1) -- node[scale=2] {$\circlearrowleft$} (mycd-3-2);
      \path (mycd-2-1) -- node[yscale=3.2, xscale=-1.5, rotate=90, yshift=-.1em] {\textasciitilde} (mycd-3-1);
      }
    ]  \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E)[p]^*\ar[r, "j"]\ar[dr, "\phi^*", swap ]\ar[d,"\circlearrowright"]& \mathrm{Coker}\beta \ar[d,"\iota", hook']\\ 
    \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E[p])^* \ar[r,"\beta^*"]\ar[dash, d,swap,
    "\psi", shift left=.5em, outer sep=.3em]&H^1(G_K,E[p])^*\\ \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E[p])\ar[r]& \mathrm{Coker}\beta\ar[u, "\iota", hook, swap]   \end{tikzcd} \]

Now, I want to add labeling (1),(2) to the loop circle.
I would like to change the loop part to the red part. Thank you very much for your help.


Something like this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[   
\begin{tikzcd}[
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},
    execute at end picture={
      \path (mycd-2-1) -- node[scale=2] {$\circlearrowleft$} node[scale=.5]{$(2)$} (mycd-3-2);
      \path ([xshift=11em]mycd-1-1) -- node[scale=2] {$\circlearrowright$} node[scale=.5]{$(1)$} ([xshift=15em]mycd-2-1);
      \path (mycd-2-1) -- node[yscale=3.2, xscale=-1.5, rotate=90, yshift=-.1em] {\textasciitilde} (mycd-3-1);
      }
    ]  
    \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E)[p]^*\ar[r, "j"]\ar[dr, "\phi^*", swap ]\ar[d,"\lambda", swap]& \mathrm{Coker}\beta \ar[d,"\iota", hook']\\ 
    \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E[p])^* \ar[r,"\beta^*"]\ar[dash, d,swap,
    "\psi", shift left=.5em, outer sep=.3em]&H^1(G_K,E[p])^*\\ \bigoplus_{v\in S} H^1(G_{K_v},E[p])\ar[r]& \mathrm{Coker}\beta\ar[u, "\iota", hook, swap]   
\end{tikzcd} 
\]

\end{document}



Thank you very much! Could you possibly adjust loop (1) to be more centered within the triangle?

Actually, I want to name the vertical map next to the loop as λ. However, in the current state, I can't do that. What should I do?

@BrauerManinobstruction See my renewed answer. Did I understand your requests?

Beautiful! Thank you very much. Your code is exactly what I was seeking for.

@BrauerManinobstruction You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer
